Volume shadow copy service (VSSVC.exe) keeps starting
I'm getting VSS errors when running Veeam backups at night. The reason appears to be that something is forcing the Volume Shadow Copy service to keep running, i.e. something is using it. It keeps starting itself and won't stop. If I kill it, the process just starts up again immediately. It's not performing a shadow copy or Veeam backup at the present time.
How else can I diagnose or identify what is causing it to run, what's using it?
Thanks.

I'm getting VSS errors what errors?

I'm often getting backup failures with VSS related errors when running Veeam backups at night, 'VSS_E_SNAPSHOT_SET_IN_PROGRESS. Code:0x80042316'. The reason is that the Volume Shadow Copy service is already running when backups start. Something is using it. This service is set to manual in Services.msc and only runs when it is required, but whatever is using it is not stopping it when finished.
At this stage, I'm having to run a scheduled task with 'net stop vss' just before backup on the problem servers, but this should not be required.

The problem is not that the service is running. The problem is that there is a snapshot in progress. You aren't going to get anywhere until you run vssadmin to list the shadows to see the datetime it was created.
